# How to find DEM elevation value at sill in semi-variogram

Tags: gstat

As semi-variograms gives semi-variance and lag distance for DEM. I want to know at what DEM elevation the sill value is flattening using penta spherical model.

Comment: This question seems to be more mathematics related than programming. And even then it is an incomplete question. Be specific.

Comment: I have digital surface model with buildings. I want to generate semivariogram for a building with slight buffer around the building. Is there any indirect way of finding the elevation value of dem where the semi-variogram is flattening. I want to use penta-spherical model for building.